# socket Errno 10060

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Im using requests to routinely download a webpage and check it for updates, but recently ive been getting these errors :

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='somehost', port=someport): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: someurl (Caused by : [Errno
>   10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond)

Now this script has been running for weeks with this issue never coming up. Could it be that the site administrator has started blocking my proxy's IP?

I should add that its not against the TOS of the site to scrape it.

Can anyone help me figure out whats the reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The remote connection timed out.

The host you are trying to connect to is not answering; it is not refusing connections, it is just not responding *at all* to connection attempts.

Perhaps the host is overloaded or down? It could also be caused by the site blocking your IP address by dropping the packets (a firewall `DROP` rule instead of a `REJECT` rule).

You can try to connect to the site from a different IP address; if those connections work fine, but not from the original address, there is a higher likelihood that you are deliberately being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can check this by trying to load the site with my browser using the same proxy.. Ill do that right now

Comment: hm, using a browser going through the same proxy i did not get this response, I even refreshed quite a few times... not sure how to proceed..

Comment: It is perfectly possible for the remote server to tar-pit your connection based on headers. This being a remote connection timeout, there is little you can do anyway.